Python default version not changing

I had installed some program which required conda after the conda installation I started having issues with stable diffusion because it requires python 3.10 version, I started encountering various errors.

In the env variables its set to python 3.10

After changing the path variable i was expecting that python --version command to output python 3.10 version.

Is this in the miniconda command prompt or in your normal cmd?

normal command prompt
